# A finite set such that $x*y=x*z \implies y=z$ and $y*x=z*x\implies y=z$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be a finite set and $*$ an associative binary operation such that $x*y=x*z \implies y=z$ and $y*x=z*x\implies y=z$, $\forall x, y, z \in G$. Prove that $(G, *) $  is a group.
I only need to prove that $(G, *) $ is a monoid because if a finite monoid has the cancellation property then it is a group. However, I can't prove this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint ** Pick some $x \in G$. Look at $\{ x,x^2,..,x^n,.. \}$.

You can find two powers $m <m+k$ such that 
$$x^{m+k}=x^m$$

This gives 
$$x^m x^k =x^m$$

Now, by cancelation law you get 
$$x x^{k}=x$$

Therefore, for each $x \in G$ there exists some $e_x=x^k$ such that 
$$x e_x=e_x x=x$$

Now, for $x , y$ show that 
$$ye_xx=ye_yx$$

Deduce from here that $G$ has an identity.

Comment: Yes, I realised that in the meantime, this is why I deleted my comment. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, note that for any $x$, left multiplication by $x$ is injective by the given properties. Then there is some $e$ such that $xe=x$. Then for any $y$, $xey=xy$, so $ey=y$ for all $y$. In particular $ee=e$, so $yee=ye$, and thus $ye=y=ey$ for all $y$, so $e$ is an identity element.